# Using one DataTable as the source in multiple UserControls in WinForms

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datatable, dataset

I have created a local DataTable in my DataSet. I then have two User Controls with Data Grids on them.

I am trying to add data to the Data Table from UserControl1 and then be able to view this data in the UserControl2.

The Current structure is - DataSet - DataTableClients

DataGrids on both user controls have DataSource property set to 'DataTableClientsBindingSource" from the DataSet.

Adding clients works fine as I can see DataGrid rows populating in the UserControl1:

```
    Dim clientsDT As DataTable = DataSet.DataTableClients
    Dim row As DataRow
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To iClientNo

        row = clientsDT.NewRow()

        row("ClientNo") = Controls("LblClient" & i.ToString()).Text
        row("Title") = Controls("CboTitle" & i.ToString()).Text
        row("FirstName") = Controls("TxtFName" & i.ToString()).Text
        row("Surname") = Controls("TxtSurname" & i.ToString()).Text
        row("ReportName") = Controls("TxtFName" & i.ToString()).Text.Substring(0, 1) & " " & Controls("TxtSurname" & i.ToString()).Text
        clientsDT.Rows.Add(row)

    Next
```

However, when I switch to my UserControl2, the DataGrid on that control is empty, even though the DataSource is set and pointing to the same DataTable.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first line of your code indicates that you are using a typed DataSet but the rest of the code is written as though you aren't. Why is that?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the same `BindingSource` in both cases. Not sure about WPF but, in WinForms, that would cause the selections in both grids to be in sync.

Comment: @Clemens - WinForms, I've just corrected it

Comment: So you're actually using `DataGridView` controls then, not `DataGrid` controls.

Comment: Does the second grid have columns but no rows, or no columns as well?

Comment: In the UserControl1 I have DataTableClientsBindingSource, which has DataTableClients as the DataMember and DataSet as DataSource

In UserControl2 I have exactly the same set up. My thinking was that I should point both Data Grids to the same data table.

The 2nd data grid has exactly the same columns

Comment: Given that the grids are inside user controls, how EXACTLY are you binding them?

Comment: How did the DataSet get in there? Did you add one to each user control in the designer? If so then they're not the same DataSet and you are probably only populating the one in the first user control. You should have a single DataSet in the form, the form should pass that one DataSet to each user control and then each user control should bind its own grid.

Comment: Well, it's probably my lack of understanding how they need to be bound... I thought setting the same Data source would bind them

Comment: You probably aren't "setting the same Data source". The fact that two things have the same name doesn't mean they are the same thing.

Comment: That's right, the Data set was added in the design view when I selected data source for both grids. OK that would explain it. Could you elaborate on best way of binding it please?

Comment: *"the Data set was added in the designer"*. Then they are two different DataSets. When you create a typed DataSet in your project, you are creating a number types, not objects. You create instances of those types at run time. Just like any other type, you can have multiple instances. If you added two TextBoxes to your form, would you expect changes to one to show up in the other? Of course not, so why should changes made in one instance of your DataSet show up in another?

Comment: Ok I get it, thanks. How would I go about using one dource for both of my usercontrols?

Comment: I would suggest a property on the user control that passes directly to and from the `DataSource` of the appropriate `BindingSource`. You can then simply assign the `DataTable` to that property in the form and Barb's your auntie. If you really want to add the `DataSet` in the designer, do so in the form. You then pass the `DataTable` to the user controls in code, e.g. the `Load` event handler.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have gone with the latter - works great, thank you!